# Static Field Initializers

Tags: c#, static

I was stuck in between my code with the implementation of Static Code Initializers. Now, here I am calling the static field "x" of Classes A and B respectively in Main. Ideally, it should be generating the output as:

```
A : 0
A.x : 5
B : 0
B.x : 5
```

But, it is generating the output as:

```
A : 0
B : 0
A.x : 5
B.x : 5
```

Please explain.

```
Code:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class A
    {
        public static A _A = new A();
        public static int x = 5;
        public A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A : " + x);
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public static B _B = new B();
        public static int x = 5;
        public B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B : " + x);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A.x : " + A.x);
            Console.WriteLine("B.x : " + B.x);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `A` and `B` don't declare static constructors, their field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of each class. In this case the CLR chose to execute both field initializers at the beginning of Main.

Comment: To get the behavior you're expecting, add empty static constructors to `A` and `B` (`static A() { }` and `static B() { }`).

Comment: @Micahel Liu I commented out both Writeline functions in Main Method, but then there was no output being generated.Ideally, I was expecting output as A:0 and B:0(as per your answer).

Comment: If you comment out the calls to WriteLine, then the "first use" never occurs, so the CLR may choose not to execute the field initializers at all. Try adding empty static constructors.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Adding empty Static Constructors worked.....Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static initialization of fields happens in non-deterministic order, try making the constructors of `A` and `B` static, and initialize the variables inside. That ensure it is initialized the first time your class is used and in the order you specified.

Comment: `try making your constructors static`, what?

Comment: declare the constructors of `A` and `B` static. Static constructors get called the first time the class is used.

Answer (score 0):

The CLR first analyzes the code in your main:

Here 2 static classes are used and hence will resolve the constructors of both in the order in which they are used.

Hence the Writeline inside the constructors are executed first and then WriteLine of your main code is executed.

If you had used Console.WriteLine for B first in main, followed by A, then B's constructor will execute first.